# update xml file within jar at runtime

Tags: java, xml

I have an xml file within my jar file. I was wondering if there is any way to update the information at runtime. Please give me some suggestions and Thanks to you ALL in advance.

Comment: More details are needed, specifically what exactly you have tried so far ? Your question is not totally clear to me as to what information you want to update .

Comment: i am working on an xml database and want to place it inside my jar file for security reasons. I want to update the xml database which is present inside the jar e.g. updating the phone number in a record. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should change the classpath to current directory so that the files in the current directory is considered as classpath (You can put the xml file outside the jar and change whenever needed in runtime)

To do that , if you are using maven to build the jar then add this in jar plugin configuration

```
<configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        </manifest>
        <manifestEntries>
          <Class-Path>.</Class-Path> <!-- . directory where the jar is -->
        </manifestEntries>
      </archive>
</configuration>
```

Then build your project to generate the jar file, Place it in a directory. Add the xml file to that directory so that while running jar it will read this xml file from the classpath (Directory of the jar now). Now you can change the xml file in runtime.

If you dont want to bundle the xml file in the jar, you can exclude it by adding this in jar plugin configuration

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>filename.xml</exclude>
</excludes>
```

Comment: Thank you my Friend, but the xml file should be placed within the jar so that the JRE will not allow users to unzip jar and read the informations. And yes, I will encrypt the database(which is the XML) once the application(connection) is closed. Thank You for Suggestion once again.